Can non-negative matrix factorization be used for binary/boolean data?
I'm circling back to non-negative matrix factorization, in particular the sklearn implementation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html
The dataset that I'm interested in trying this method out on is binary/boolean data.  Technically, all the values are non-negative so it should be able to work but I'm unsure if there are certain assumptions that I would be violating in using binary/boolean data using this methodology.
Does anyone have any insight on non-negative matrix factorization and if it can be used for binary/boolean data? If so, what parameters in sklearn should be adjusted to accommodate this type of data?

What is the goal?

To perform dimensionality reduction in method similar to this: https://github.com/dpeerlab/spectra but adapted for binary data instead of compositional data.  Currently using diffusion maps for this but wanted to try out some other methods to compare.
